# can not import pascalize, depascalize from humps package python

Tags: python, virtualenv, linux-mint, virtual-environment

### Hello my friends plz help me with this strange problem

1-In my terminal of linux mint I can easily install package humps and then use `from humps import pascalize, depascalize` with no problem

2-But when I create a virtualenv of pythonand I can install package humps and I can use `import humps` but I can't use `from humps import pascalize, depascalize` or `humps.pascalize("some_string")`
it will cause an **ImportError: cannot import name 'pascalize'** and **AttributeError: module 'humps' has no attribute 'pascalize'**

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that you typed `pip install humps` instead of `pip install pyhumps`.

Or add in your requirements file:

```
pyhumps==3.7.1
```

> [Pypi - pyhumps](https://pypi.org/project/pyhumps/)
>
> [Documentation - humps](https://humps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)